# javascript, condition in if statement for recognizing image src

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem getting the condition in this if statement to work, i've tried `getElementById` & `src.indexOf` but I am still very new to this. I am trying to replace the blank/ball image with the x/pikachu image only if the blank image is currently showing, so if there was one of the other images there it wouldn't replace it. It doesn't seem to recognize the condition I have in there as true, any idea why? 
i've also tried:`document.getElementById(bn).src=blank` & `document.images[bn].src==blank` & `document.pokemon.bn.src==blank` 
looking for a way to verify if the current source of the image is the var blank.
thank you

```
 var x = "pikachu.jpg";
 var o = "Meowth.jpg";
 var blank = "ball.jpg";             

 function b1Move(imageName){
 temp2=imageName;
 if(document.pokemon[temp2].src==blank)  
 document.pokemon[temp2].src=x;
 cMove();
 }
```

and the html for the images looks like this:

```
 <a href="javascript:b1Move('b1')"><img src="ball.jpg" height=150 width=150 name=b1         
 id =b1  > </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `src` property gives the fully resolved URL. You probably want to use the `src` attribute, which stays the same:

```
if( document.pokemon[temp2].getAttribute("src") == blank)
    document.pokemon[temp2].setAttribute("src",x);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
if(document.pokemon[temp2].src.indexOf(blank) != -1)
```

since src is the full url.. then you can check it it contains your image name